# DPD Api Label format

Tags: api, label, dpd

We are building a program to place shipping directly from our system to the DPD api. Everything works fine and we are getting the label in response.

I don't know what format it is. The documentation of the API is very poor. Does anybody has an idea what it could bee? It doesn't look like ZPL:

```
N
```

Q822,24
R40,0
S4
D15
ZB

A760,120,1,1,1,1,N,"DPD Local"
A735,080,1,1,1,1,N,"www.dpdlocal.co.uk"
A706,033,1,1,1,1,N,"Sender"
A690,033,1,1,1,1,N,""
A674,033,1,1,1,1,N,"2 SABRE WAY"
A658,033,1,1,1,1,N,""
A642,033,1,1,1,1,N,"PETERBOROUGH"
A626,033,1,1,1,1,N,"PETERBOROUGH"
A610,033,1,1,1,1,N,"PE1 5EJ"
A606,124,1,1,1,1,N,"Phone:"
A706,158,1,1,1,1,N,"Account:"
A588,033,1,1,1,1,N,"Delivery Address"
A003,035,0,4,1,1,N,""
A003,060,0,4,1,1,N,"3 SABRE WAY"
A003,085,0,4,1,1,N,""
A003,110,0,4,1,1,N,"PETERBOROUGH"
A003,135,0,4,1,1,N,"PETERBOROUGH"
A003,160,0,4,1,1,N,"PE1 5EJ"
A183,160,0,4,1,1,N,"United Kingdom"
A480,150,0,4,2,2,N,""
A003,198,0,1,1,1,N,"Contact"
A003,213,0,1,1,1,N,"Phone"
A003,265,0,1,1,1,N,"Consignment"
A003,283,0,1,1,1,N,"Ref"
A003,228,0,1,1,1,N,"Info"
A120,198,0,1,1,1,N,"SEND CONTACT 1"
A120,213,0,1,1,1,N,""
A120,228,0,1,1,1,N,""
A120,243,0,1,1,1,N,""
A120,265,0,1,1,1,N,""
A120,283,0,1,1,1,N,"MY REF 1"
A120,298,0,1,1,1,N,"MY REF 2"
A120,313,0,1,1,1,N,"MY REF 3"
A463,195,0,1,1,1,N,"Packages"
A453,245,0,1,1,1,N,"Total Weight"
A463,210,0,4,1,1,N,"1 of 1"
A463,260,0,4,1,1,N,"5 kg"
A003,397,0,1,1,1,N,"Track"
A695,390,0,1,1,1,N,"Service"
A003,350,0,4,1,2,N,"1597"
A103,350,0,4,1,1,N,"6885 0239 32T"
A160,525,0,1,1,1,N,"      06/04/21 18:55 Web 4.3.55-api      "
B010,550,0,1,3,6,200,N,"%0PE15EJ15976885023932808826"
A140,780,0,3,1,1,N,"0PE1 5EJ1 5976 8850 2393 2808 8262"
A479,342,0,4,1,2,N,"       BY 1030 PCL"
A190,490,0,4,1,1,N,"   808-GB - PE1 5EJ   "
A010,420,0,2,2,2,N,""
A008,475,0,4,2,3,N,"LOCAL"
A645,475,0,4,2,3,N,"1631"
A100,390,0,4,3,4,N,"GB-PE1 5EJ"
LO001,330,765,10
LO001,025,765,1
LO001,192,590,1
LO001,330,765,10
LO765,001,1,330
LO001,001,1,330
LO715,025,1,306
LO592,025,1,306
LO001,001,765,1
LO430,192,1,138
P1
N
"""

Comment: I'm currently attempting to work with the DPD API too. You're right, the documentation is bad, so if anyone has any examples of working with this API it'd be great to see!

Comment: I have a working example made in Laravel / php. I don't think it would be very cood the publish the whole code here. If you are interested, let me know how I can send it to you

Comment: That would be great Chris - there's not a DM system on here is there?

Comment: I don't think there is anything here. And I also think this question is also not the correct place to talk about the whole api.

Comment: This is ZPL. But you can fetch PDF or GIF from DPD Api too